# Regex to match file names in textfile

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, gulp

Using Node.js, I'm parsing a file and building an array of found image names.
I'm wondering if anyone can help me punch holes in my regex. So far I haven't been able to break it.

```
var filename = (line.match(/((?:((?:[^\r\n\t\f\/])*)\.(?:(png|gif|jpe?g|pdf|xml|apng|svg|mng)\b)))/gmi) || []).pop();
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an actual list of strings you're supposed to be matching?

Comment: For ease of testing, I've added my test strings to a regex101: https://regex101.com/r/rS4dF7/3

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @rickysullivan You're looking for some pretty jacked up file names.  Are those real-world examples?

Answer (score 1):

Without a list of examples, I [simplified your regular expression](http://bit.ly/1jZnjYk) to this:

`/(\b\S+\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g|pdf|xml|apng|svg|mng)\b)/gi`

Please note that the `\S+` is pretty liberal with what it will match; which means ANY non-whitespace character.  So, if you want to make it more strict for matching **legal characters**, I'd suggest you modify that part with a character class.